# What happens to the resources that aren't cleaned up when you use _exit in UNIX?

Tags: c++, c, unix

I've read that you can call either `exit` or `_exit` when you wish to terminate a process in UNIX, and also that exit frees resources (the style used when we return from main) where _exit immediately terminates without cleanup.

What is the impact of closing a program with _exit with regard to the operating environment, and why would you want to use it?

Comment: I'm going to leave real answers to more knowledgeable people, but the program usually will call _exit if it has NO idea how to continue.  If you throw two exceptions at the same time for instance.  Generally it's used it stack unwinding would be a bad idea for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in resources freed when exiting with `_exit` versus `exit` unless you have installed `atexit` handlers. Named shared memory objects, SysV IPC resources, files in the filesystem, etc. will not be destroyed on either type of exit; memory allocated to the process (in fact, its whole virtual memory space), file descriptors, etc. will be destroyed either way. For details read the documentation in POSIX:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html

Usually the only important difference is that stdio FILE objects might not be flushed (some writes may be lost) if you use `_exit`.

Comment: You are ignoring that C/C++ automatically install `atexit` handlers before `main` is even called.

Comment: File streams(descriptors) are resources as well. exit() will clean these up while _exit() will not.

Comment: @Tux-D: My answer mentions that FILE objects will not be flushed by `_exit`. Whether they are flushed or not, however, the resource is freed. The underlying file descriptor is closed by `_exit`, and the userspace buffers cease to exist when the process's entire virtual memory space is discarded.

Comment: @David: Neither C nor C++ "automatically install `atexit` handlers". Both languages specify some things to happen on program termination - for C, just flushing/closing open FILE objects, and for C++, also running static destructors. These actions will not take place if `_exit` is used.

Comment: @R..: That's the POSIX standard you quoted, and POSIX is oblivious of C++. Here is how Linux acomplishes this: http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.2.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---cxa_finalize.html . The Itanium ABI puts calls to destructors for global data on the same list that is used for functions registered with `atexit`.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page:

`exit`:

> The exit() function first calls all functions registered  by
>        atexit(3C),  in  the  reverse  order  of their registration,
>        except that  a  function  is  called  after  any  previously
>        registered  functions  that  had  already been called at the
>        time it was registered.

`_exit`:

> The  _Exit()  and   _exit()   functions   are   functionally
>        equivalent.  They  do  not  call  functions  registered with
>        atexit(), do not call any registered signal handlers, and do
>        not flush open streams.

In other words `exit` and `_exit` still do resource (such as file handles and allocated heap memory) reclamation if the OS does so, but user-defined things such as static destructors won't be called, and files won't be flushed in the `_exit` case.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is automatically equipped with some default `atexit()` handlers. Call `exit()` and

- Streams for files and pipes that are still open will be flushed and closed.
- Global data will be destructed.

Call `_exit()` and

- Streams for files and pipes that are still open will not be flushed. You most likely will lose data in output files.
- Global data will not be destructed.

In both cases,

- Any memory you have allocated is recovered.
- Exited child processes that you did not reap will still be in the process table (However, zombies don't appear to be the big problem they were long ago.)
- Still-running child processes become orphans and are adopted in the `init` process.